# An equiangular hexagon has side lengths 3,4,5,3,4 and 5 units in that order. What is the area?

Tags: geometry

An equiangular hexagon has side lengths 3,4,5,3,4 and 5 units in that order. What is the area? Express your answer as a common fraction in simplest radical form.

Comment: did you try anything yourself?

Answer (score 3):

Hint...draw a rectangle which encloses the hexagon and which has a pair of sides coincident with the sides of length $3$, and whose other sides touch the vertices of the hexagon between the sides $4$ and $5$.

You can easily work out the area of the rectangle and subtract the four right angled triangles...

Comment: i answered it by coordinate method

Answer (score 1):

If you draw an equilateral triangle containing the hexagon, you find that the hexagon is just the equlateral triangle of lengths 3+4+5 minus 3 equalateral traingles of length 3,4, and 5. So, using the equilateral triangle formula of area= side squared times root 3/4 we find it is just 144 root 3/4 minus ((9+16+25) root 3/4) which simplifies to 47 root 3/2

Thus, 47 sqrt. 3 all over 2 is the answer

Answer (score 0):

Divide the hexagon up like this:
[image]

The total angles in a hexagon are $720^0 ((6-2)\cdot 180)$ so each one is $120^0$
By the cosine rule($a^2=b^2+c^2-2bc\cos(A)$), the side marked $k$ is $\sqrt{37}$. Hence the area of the middle rectangle is $5\sqrt{37}$. The area of the two triangles is found by $\frac{1}{2}ab\sin(C)$, so here it is $3\sqrt3$. There are two of them, so combined with the rectangle, the total area is $$6\sqrt{3}+5\sqrt{37}$$

Comment: How do you know the central quadrilateral is a rectangle?

Comment: If the central quadrilateral were a rectangle, then the two triangles would be isosceles (with angles 120, 30, and 30). But $3\not=4$, so they are not isosceles.